# What is the most reliable android clock to use?

Tags: android, clock

Im implementing my own double tap zoom for my OpenGL ES app and am having issues with `System.currentTimeMillis()`: It seems like when the main thread gets a little busy, it isnt as accurate. 2 taps 200ms apart will show as 600ms apart. **What is the most reliable clock to use in Android?** I know theres quite a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.currentTimeMillis()` call is quite accurate. The problem is likely that your handler for the tap isn't firing immediately, but because of the load is delayed a few hundred ms.